# Sudden limited access on wired network, Windows 7 RC1

Tags: windows-7, networking, limited-access

From time to time (twice a day, once a week - hard to tell really), I suddenly get "Limited access" on my internet connection, and I see no obvious reason for this.

- It's on a wired network, so no unstable WLAN-issues here
- It's not the router nor the modem, everything works fine with my two other computers (both wired and WLAN).
- Motherboard with NIC is an Asus Striker Extreme (2x 1000mbit). Tried both. Both have the same problem.
- I'm running Windows 7 RC. This never happened when using Vista. Could possibly be some driver not being stable in Win7, but if so - which one? Tried several motherboard driver versions (including NIC-driveres).
- Disabling and then enabling the network connection often fixes it. Not always though - sometimes i just have to wait for a few minutes.
- No error messages anywhere

Anyone seen this before? I'd really like this fixed, it's damn annoying.

Comment: Can you check the DNS settings and try to ping IP address if you still have the issue?

Comment: Although I'd like to try this, I no longer can, as this is almost seven years old.

Comment: Thank you for your update, yeah I do agree with you. Sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Cisco VPN Client installed? That caused me massive problems with my Win7 setup, and something similar to what you describe.

Comment: Yep, yep i do. Will uninstall it and see if that helps. :-)